# Scala cats, traverse Seq

Tags: scala, traversal, scala-cats

I know I can traverse `List`s

```
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

def doMagic(item: A): M[B] = ???
val list: List[A] = ???
val result: M[List[B]] = list.traverse(doMagic)
```

And I can convert a `Seq` back and forth to `List`

```
val seq: Seq[A] = ???
val result: M[Seq[B]] = seq.toList.traverse(doMagic).map(_.toSeq)
```

But can I also traverse `Seq` without the boilerplate?

```
val seq: Seq[A] = ???
val result: M[Seq[B]] = seq.traverse(doMagic)
```

Or what's an easy way to get an instance of Traverse[Seq]?

Comment: May I ask why exactly you want to keep wrapping and unwrapping `Seq` to `List` and back, instead of converting everything to `List` once and then work with that?

Comment: In the project I'm working on `Seq` is used everywhere, not sure why. Perhaps we could've been using `List` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cats does not provide typeclass instances for `Seq`, so besides implementing it yourself you're stuck with the conversion.

As to why, there's an ongoing discussion in an (somewhat old) Cats [issue](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1222). To sum it up, you won't know enough about `Seq` underlying characteristics to make sure some of the typeclasses instances laws hold.

EDIT : Nevermind, it exists now, see linked thread

Answer (score 1):

As of cats 2.3, support for `immutable.Seq` is now built in. See "Where are implicit instances for Seq?" on the [FAQ](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html) or [this PR](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/3620) where the functionality was added.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the conversion from all `Seq` to `List` will always succeed in your code, you can simply transfer the `Traverse` structure from `List` to `Seq` over an (pseudo-)isomorphism:

```
  def traverseFromIso[F[_], Z[_]]
    (forward: F ~> Z, inverse: Z ~> F)
    (implicit zt: Traverse[Z])
  : Traverse[F] = new Traverse[F] {
    def foldLeft[A, B](fa: F[A], b: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B = zt.foldLeft(forward(fa), b)(f)
    def foldRight[A, B](fa: F[A], lb: Eval[B])(f: (A, Eval[B]) => Eval[B]): Eval[B] =
      zt.foldRight(forward(fa), lb)(f)

    def traverse[G[_], A, B]
      (fa: F[A])
      (f: (A) ⇒ G[B])
      (implicit appG: Applicative[G])
    : G[F[B]] = {
      (zt.traverse(forward(fa))(f)(appG)).map(zb => inverse(zb))
    }
  }
```

This isn't really an isomorphism, because the conversion from `Seq` to `List` can fail badly (e.g. if the sequence is infinite). What it does is simply converting `Seq` to `List` back and forth, and forwarding all method calls to those of `Traverse[List]`.

Now you can use this method to build an instance of `Traverse[Seq]`:

```
 implicit val seqTraverse: Traverse[Seq] = traverseFromIso(
   new FunctionK[Seq, List] { def apply[X](sx: Seq[X]): List[X] = sx.toList },
   new FunctionK[List, Seq] { def apply[X](lx: List[X]): Seq[X] = lx }
 )
```

Full code snippet (compiles with scala 2.12.4 and cats 1.0.1):

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.arrow.FunctionK
import scala.language.higherKinds

object TraverseFromIso {

  // This method can build you a `Traversable[Seq]` from
  // an `Traversable[List]` and a pair of polymorphic conversion
  // functions:

  def traverseFromIso[F[_], Z[_]]
    (forward: F ~> Z, inverse: Z ~> F)
    (implicit zt: Traverse[Z])
  : Traverse[F] = new Traverse[F] {
    def foldLeft[A, B](fa: F[A], b: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B = zt.foldLeft(forward(fa), b)(f)
    def foldRight[A, B](fa: F[A], lb: Eval[B])(f: (A, Eval[B]) => Eval[B]): Eval[B] =
      zt.foldRight(forward(fa), lb)(f)

    def traverse[G[_], A, B]
      (fa: F[A])
      (f: (A) ⇒ G[B])
      (implicit appG: Applicative[G])
    : G[F[B]] = {
      (zt.traverse(forward(fa))(f)(appG)).map(zb => inverse(zb))
    }
  }

  // A little demo
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // To instantiate a `Traverse[Seq]`, we have to provide
    // two natural transformations (from List to Seq and back):

    implicit val seqTraverse: Traverse[Seq] = traverseFromIso(
      new FunctionK[Seq, List] { def apply[X](sx: Seq[X]): List[X] = sx.toList },
      new FunctionK[List, Seq] { def apply[X](lx: List[X]): Seq[X] = lx }
    )

    // do stuff with `Traversable[Seq]` here
  }
}
```