# cats.sequence executes before all Futures complete even if lifted to EitherT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to execute a future-returning operation on multiple items, and if any one of the operations fails, I need to execute custom rollback logic.  However, the critical bit here is that the rollback logic MUST execute after all of the non-failing operations have completed.

Example:

```
  def fn(thing: Thing): EitherT[Future, Error, Thing] = {
    if (someCondition) {
      EitherT(Future.successful(Right(thing)))
    } else {
      EitherT(Future.successful(Left(error)))
    }
  }

  def rollback(): EitherT[...] = {
    // general cleanup
  }

  List(things).map(fn).sequence.leftMap {
    case err =>
      rollback()
      rrr
    
  }
```

Based on the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000842/resolve-seqfutureeithera-seqb-scala-cats), I understand that, if my operation were returning a Future[Thing], the sequence would complete as soon as *any* operation failed.  However, using EitherT, I would think that, because all the Futures return a success (of either Left or Right), the sequence should not complete until all the operations' futures complete.

However, what I am seeing is that my `rollback` function is executing while the non-failed operations are still executing.

Is there an alternative to sequence I should be using here?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because `EiherT` should also short-circuit on the first **Left** as a normal `Either` would do; that is the joke of using the transformer. Just use a normal `Future[Either[Error, A]]` instead. Also `map` + `sequence` is `traverse` but I believe for futures the behavior is different.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks - Yes, I think that's true.  It looks like Validation/ValidationNel would have been the way to go, but in our case, it's EitherT all the way down, so I have to do a bunch of ridiculous mapping to keep everything as a Successful(Right) until after the .sequence, and then map it back to the original Either.  Ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Futures run eagerly, and will keep going no matter what. Perhaps change `fn` signature to

```
def fn(thing: Thing): Future[Either[Error, Thing]]
```

and then `sequence` before constructing `EitherT` which should ensure all the `Future`s complete before next step in the chain

```
EitherT { 
  List(things)
    .map(fn)         // List[Future[Either[Error, Thing]]
    .sequence        // Future[List[Either[Error, Thing]]] (here all complete)
    .map(_.sequence) // Future[Either[Error, List[Thing]]]
}.leftMap { err =>
  rollback()
  rrr
}
```

Comment: Ah, also good thought.  Sadly, pretty much every method in our system is EitherT.   Given that, I am wondering if doing a collect instead of sequence would avoid the short circuit.